# Why does jQuery.find not work with fragments

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this jQuery snippet:

```
var html = '<div id="a">abc</div>' +
    '<div id="b">def</div>';
$(html).find('#a')
```

return an empty result (`[]`)? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8hLw/))

And how can I access the `#a` div without inserting it into the actual DOM document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `#a` is the parent node. `find()` searches the children/grandchildren, etc. You would need to wrap that again in order to use `find()`.

```
var $html = $('<div id="a">abc</div><div id="b">def</div>');
var x = $('<div></div>').append($html);
console.log(x.find('#a'));
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/afeZAwi/1/edit)**

`filter()` does what you're looking for:

```
var $html = $('<div id="a">abc</div><div id="b">def</div>');
console.log($html.filter('#a'));
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/afeZAwi/2/edit)**

Answer (score 4):

Find looks in children nodes.  Because `#a` is your top node, it will not find it.  Either wrap your fragment in a parent element, or use `.filter('#a')`.